# How to start/stop a python script as a service at a specific time on CentOS?

Tags: python, services, centos-7, systemd

I am trying to put a python script on a VPS running CentOS 7, that crawls some stock data online from a web service. What I want to do is to set this script as an OS service that start/stops at a specific time.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use traditional cron (`man cron`), basically do `crontab -e` and follow the instructions.

or more modern but not necessarily better [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers).

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided is to start python script at scheduled time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982366/4511992